# Проверка на существование файла

Tags: jquery

Написал скрипт поиска картинки для нужного мне блока:

```
$('.craft').each(function() {
    var craft_id = $(this).attr('jet-id').toLowerCase();
    var that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/img/crafts/' + craft_id + '.png',
        success: function() {
            that.find('.craft-searcher').attr('src', '/img/crafts/' + craft_id + '.png');
        },
        error: function() {
            that.find('.craft-searcher').attr('src', '/img/crafts/' + craft_id + '.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

Работа скрипта заключается в поиске картинки формата `.png` и если такая картинка не найдена, то к блоку будет прикреплена картинка формата `.jpg`.

**Вопрос:** как прикрепить другую картинку, если не были найдены ни `.png`, ни `.jpg`? Скрипт-то способен обработать лишь один fail().

UPD: заметил, что скрипт делает поиск дважды. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/img/crafts/' + craft_id + '.png',
    success: function() {
        that.find('.craft-searcher').attr('src', '/img/crafts/' + craft_id + '.png');
    },
    error: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/img/crafts/' + craft_id + '.jpg',
        success: function() {
          that.find('.craft-searcher').attr('src', '/img/crafts/' + craft_id + '.jpg');
        },
        error: function() {
          that.find('.craft-searcher').attr('src', '/img/crafts/' + craft_id + '.gif');
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Для ответа на

> скрипт делает поиск дважды. Почему?

в вопросе недостаточно кода.